# Compile Error on ExportAsFixedFormat - with PpFixedFormatIntent parameter (saving PowerPoint as PDF)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

With an Excel VBA (office 365) script I create a PowerPoint with one slide.

For saving this PPT as a PDF I use:

```vb
objpres.ExportAsFixedFormat Myfile, FixedFormatType:=2, RangeType:=3
```

To improve the resolution I added the parameter PpFixedFormatIntent:=2:

```vb
objpres.ExportAsFixedFormat Myfile, FixedFormatType:=2, RangeType:=3, PpFixedFormatIntent:=2
```

I get

> compile Error: Named Argument not Found

Activated references.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The parameter name is **Intent** rather than ppFixedFormatIntent. I'm not seeing any issues with the following code:

```
ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "c:\PresentationPDF.pdf", _
    ppFixedFormatTypePDF, Intent:=2
```

This also works:

```
  ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "c:\PresentationPDF.pdf", _
    ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
```

The RangeType argument isn't necessary.